# Implementing warm restarts in SGD in R (Keras)

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, gradient-descent, hyperparameters

I am trying to add learning rate restarts - i.e. my own much less sophisticated version of *Stochastic Gradient Descent with Warm Restarts*, by Loshchilov and Hutter (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03983) to my sequence predictor CNN model.
My idea, as a first experiment, was to have the learning rate start at 0.3 and decrease by half at each epoch. Then, at every 15th epoch, it would go back to 0.3.

```
LR<-0.3
optimizer_sgd(lr=LR,nesterov = TRUE)

lr_schedule<-function(epoch) {
    model_big$optimizer$lr=LR/(2 ^ (epoch%%15))
  }

cb_lr<-callback_learning_rate_scheduler(lr_schedule)

model_big%>%
  compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'sgd',metrics = 'accuracy')

history<-model_big%>%
  fit(x=list(x1,x2,x3),y=y,epochs = 31,callbacks=c(cb_lr))
```

However, I got the following error:

```
    Epoch 1/31
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RuntimeError: Evaluation error: unused argument (lr = 0.00999999977648258).

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/Users/d/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1712, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/Users/d/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1180, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch)
  File "/Users/d/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 63, in on_epoch_begin
    callback.on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs)
  File "/Users/d/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 611, in on_epoch_begin
    lr = self.schedule(epoch, lr=lr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/call.py", line 21, in python_function
    raise RuntimeError(res[kErrorKey])
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Discussion in https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/462

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by *skeydan* in the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/462), the learning rate scheduler function has to be defined with two parameters, one for the epoch (indexed from 0) and another for the current learning rate. The function must also return the new learning rate value. Check the documentation for more details.

My contribution to the question is in regards your initial intention on implementing the SGD with Warm Restarts in R Keras. Here I am sharing my implementation with the community.

```
lr_max <- 1e-2
lr_min <- 1e-5
lr_t_0 <- 10
lr_t_mult <- 2

lr_t_i <- lr_t_0
lr_t_prev <- 0

LearningRateScheduler <- function(epoch, lr) {

  lr_t_curr <- (epoch - lr_t_prev) %% lr_t_i

  new_lr <- (lr_min
             + 1/2 * (lr_max - lr_min)
             * (1 + cos(lr_t_curr / (lr_t_i - 1) * pi)))

  if ((lr_t_curr + 1) == lr_t_i) {
    lr_t_prev <<- epoch + 1
    lr_t_i <<- lr_t_i * lr_t_mult
  }

  new_lr
}
```

It can be easily tested with the following loop

```
epochs <- 150
lr <- numeric(length = epochs)
for (e in seq(1, epochs, by = 1)) {
  lr[e] <- LearningRateScheduler(e - 1, NA)
}
```

The results are aligned with the figures in the mentioned paper.

[image: SGD with Warm Restarts in R Keras]

[image: GD with Warm Restarts in R Keras in log scale]